# Module Homomorphisms between two simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I have been given the following statements to prove:
Given 2 R-Modules: $M$ , $N$ and

$f : M \rightarrow N$

where  $f$ is non-trivial then:

a) if $N$ is a simple module then  $f$  is surjective

b) if $M$ is a simple module then  $f$  is injective

I am working with commutative rings and the only previous result I have on simple modules is that they are always cyclic

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at the kernel of $f$ for $b)$?

Comment: Welcome. If the ring $R$ is a field, for example $\Bbb R$, a $R-$module is called a (real) vector space. Aren't vector lines simple modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally figured it out.
For proposition a) the reasoning is that  $ker(f)$  is by definition a submodule, and therefore it has to be either $\{0\}$ or $M$ itself, therefore either  $f$  is trivial, which isn't allowed, or f is injective ($ker(f) = \{ 0 \} \Leftrightarrow f$ is injective)

For b) the reasoning is the same but using that the image of $f$ is also a submodule